# find minimum of a function defined by integration in Mathematica

Tags: math-software, mathematica

I need to find the minimum of a function $f(t) = \int_0^1\!g(t,x)\,dx$. What I did in mathematica is as follows:

```
f[t_] = NIntegrate[g[t,x],{x,-1,1}]
FindMinimum[f[t],{t,t0}]
```

However mathematica halts at the first try, because NIntegrate does not work with the symbolic t. Although Plot[f[t],{t,0,1}] works perferctly, FindMinimum stops at the initial point.

Any way to get around it? Thanks!

Comment: What's g[t,x]? If you have an explicit expression, we might manage to be more helpful.

Comment: Also, it should be f[t_]:=... ; you need delayed evaluation instead of immediate evaluation of the RHS. Also changing the LHS of the definition to f[t_?NumericQ] might help. This is because FindMinimum[], unlike Plot[], does not have the HoldAll attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474961/find-minimum-of-a-function-defined-by-integration-in-mathematica

Comment: Bah, I don't really hang around in StackOverflow... XD too bad my comment was late!

Comment: thank you guys!. next time i will ask on SO instead.

Answer (score 1):

*OP's [equivalent question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474961/find-minimum-of-a-function-defined-by-integration-in-mathematica) was already answered. This is [the accepted answer by Andrew Moylan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474961/find-minimum-of-a-function-defined-by-integration-in-mathematica/3475061#3475061).*

---

Try this:

```
In[58]:= g[t_, x_] := t^3 - t + x^2

In[59]:= f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[g[t, x], {x, -1, 1}]

In[60]:= FindMinimum[f[t], {t, 1}]

Out[60]= {-0.103134, {t -> 0.57735}}

In[61]:= Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Two relevant changes I made to your code:

1. Define f with `:=` instead of with `=`. This effectively gives a definition for f "later", when the user of f has supplied the values of the arguments. See [SetDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html).
2. Define f with `t_?NumericQ` instead of `t_`. This says, t can be anything numeric (Pi, 7, 0, etc). But not anything non-numeric (t, x, "foo", etc).